# Lucene Prefix Search for Indexed data through Standard Analyzer

Tags: search, lucene, standards, prefix

I am creating index using Lucene 3.6.0 for Java. They are built using Standard Analyzer. Is there any way I can perform prefix search with lucene i.e. i want the results to start with the specified search string without changing the analyzer used for indexing?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you mean queries like "work*" to find "work", "worker", "working", etc. you can already perform those queries using text analyzed with the Standard Analyzer.

documented here:  http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches